# How long does it take for a Poppler to mature?

Tags: futurama

How long does it take for a Poppler (baby Omicronian) to mature? I ask this because there have been many hints that Earth will be attacked (possibly by Morbo's species). But if it is an Omicronian, then how long does it take for a Poppler to become an adult?

In "Problem with Popplers," we see that there are billions of little Popplers that were eaten alone. One Poppler that Leela found was mature after only a couple of weeks. With that said, it should mean that the Omicronian Empire grows exponentially really fast, but that doesn't appear to be the case in terms of their army.

So how long does it take for a Poppler to become a fully grown adult?

Comment: It is true...the Omicronians WOULD have an empire that grew exponentially, but they keep sending their warriors into battle, and losing several hundred each day. This is how Lrrr maintains control over the popultaion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't known. But probably not for many decades.

However there are other factors that prevent them from growing exponentially and evidence for all of it.

**Most Babies don't survive** - While the Omicronians are upset, they don't seem nearly as upset as we would be under similar circumstances. This is because, like creatures on Earth that leave large clutches of babies abandoned, only a small fraction will survive to adulthood. On this planet alone there are probably all of these threats and more:

- Cannibalism
- Vicious Animals
- Bad Weather
- Natural Disasters like floods or fires
- Alien races discovering you are delicious

**They commit matricide, and probably patricide** - "When our species grows up, we eat our moms." The Omicronians eventually eat their parents when they mature. Exactly when isn't clear, but it is implied that it is connected with gaining maturity. Call it an Omicronian Bar Mitzvah. This also implies a near steady-state population for the Omicronians, which may be why they prefer to conquer and then leave planets. And may also be the reason why they have not taken over large parts of the universe.

**Larger issues with Cannibalism** - If the Omicronians eat their parents, they possibly also eat others of their own race. (Hence the cannibalism bullet on the above list.) And that too would serve to reduce their population and standing army.

**Long maturation time** - As I mention above. The Omicronians certainly age slowly. Otherwise Lrrr and Ndnd would have been consumed many years ago by their children.

---

**Update: In Light of "T.: The Terrestrial"** - While we know now that Omicronians age similarly to humans at least from awakened poppler stage until teenagerdom, we still don't really know how long the poppler stage is and we don't know how long it is until they reach the mother-eating stage.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered in the [Futurama live event](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/23929909/highlight/275846) (see at 30:10) :

David X Cohen said 12.7 years.

Comment: 12.7 years to become a teenager.  Whether that's mature is a question that's frustrated parents for millennia.