# How does someone become the leader of Omicron?

Tags: futurama

In the Poppler episode, Popplers are dumped onto a nursing planet, which puts all Popplers into specific areas.

How does one obtain leadership in Omicron? It doesn't seem like it has to do with a royal family. So how do they determine the leader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Since the Omicronians have an emperor, it is clear they have some sort of [monarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy) as their primary government. The Omicronians are ruled by [Emperor Lrrr](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Lrrr) and his wife [Ndnd](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Ndnd). Since younger members of the species eat older members, I suspect ascension to the throne is liable to be based in some sort of dominance behavior likely including the killing and eating of the standing regent.**

They have an advanced technological base able to build a space-capable fleet of starships, military development of weapons, interplanetary communications and at least a primitive form of cable television as well as the ability to receive signals on the VHF frequencies (facilitating their habit of watching 20th century television). Their society appears to be quite advanced. They do not keep their young on their home planet and it has been shown that the species is quite competitive. Their offspring claim to eat their mothers when they get older. (The Problem with Popplers.)

> Omicron Persei 8 is a planet inhabited by large aliens that frequently attempt to invade Earth. The Omicronians are ruled by Emperor Lrrr and his wife Ndnd. It is a habitable planet orbiting the star Omicron Persei, which is about 1000 light years from Earth; this convenient coincidence allows the Omicronians in the 31st century to view 21st century television broadcasts. [--Futurama Wiki > Omicron Persei 8](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Omicron_Persei_8)

To see other Omicronian issues in their society, see the excellent StackExchange answer: [Poplar Maturity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18708/2765).

Answer (score 2):

They kill their parents or the current Emperor.  In the episode Lrrreconcilable Ndndifferences Grrl asks "Hey, cool cape. Were'd you get it?" Lrrr's response is "What, this old thing? I murdered my father." ([citation](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript%3aLrrreconcilable_Ndndifferences))  This strongly implies that his father was the ruler previous to him and Lrrr is the only member of his species I can recal wearing a cape, implying it signifies his status as their leader

Comment: Lrrr was leader before the mention of killing the father.  In the early episodes that had Omicronians, it shows that Lrrr was the leader.  If Lrrr had to kill his father to become leader he would have to kill his father after the poker tournament (Into the Wild Green Yonder), If that were true, then Lrrr wouldn't have been the leader of Omicon in the early episodes.